# Calculating the angular velocity

Tags: trigonometry, physics, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

I have an inverted pendulum with a accelerometer mounted on the top that at rest gives me a vector up opposite to gravity, which is used to calculate the angle of the pendulum. Is it possible to calculate the angular velocity from this information?

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian of the pendulum in xy-plane
$$L=T-V=\frac12m(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)-m\,g\,y$$
where x and y are coordinates of center of mass m. If we assume that $\theta$ is the angle between x-axis and the rod of pendulum it follows that
$$x=l\cos(\theta)$$
$$\dot x=-l\sin(\theta)\,\dot \theta$$
$$y=l\sin(\theta)$$
$$\dot y=l\cos(\theta)\,\dot \theta$$
where l is the distance between origin and center of mass. By rewriting the Lagrangian
$$L=\frac12m\bigg((-l\sin(\theta)\,\dot \theta)^2+(l\cos(\theta)\,\dot \theta)^2\bigg)-m\,g\,l\sin(\theta)$$
$$L=\frac12m\,l^2(\dot \theta)^2-m\,g\,l\sin(\theta)$$
The equations of motion are
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \theta}\bigg)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}=M$$
where M is the function of moment. For sake of simplicity we assume that M=0.
$$\ddot \theta-\frac gl \cos(\theta)=0$$

From here you have two options: you can linearize around $\pi/2$ or use numerical methods. If you use linearity then
$$\cos(\theta=\pi/2)\approx \cos(\pi/2)-\sin(\pi/2)(\alpha)+O(\epsilon^2)=-\alpha$$ 
where $\alpha=\theta-\pi/2$
and therefore
$$\ddot \alpha-\frac gl \alpha=0$$
which has the solution $a=\sqrt{g/l}$
$$\alpha(t)=\frac{a}{2}\bigg(e^{at}+e^{-at}\bigg)=\alpha \cosh(\alpha\,t)$$
and
$$\dot \alpha(t)=\frac{a^2}{2}\bigg(e^{at}-e^{-at}\bigg)=\alpha^2 \sinh(\alpha\,t)$$
which you can use for a parametric relationship between angle and velocity.